# Raspberry Pi and Bluemix - TypeError for publishEvent()

Tags: raspberry-pi, ibm-cloud, iot

Hey I followed a tutorial at https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/04/02/tutorial-using-a-raspberry-pi-python-iot-twilio-bluemix/ and a line is giving me hell.

```
client.publishEvent("raspberrypi",options["deviceId"], "input", myData)
```

TypeError: publishEvent() takes at least 6 arguments (5 given)

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client has recently changed, the 6th argument that it expects is [message format](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/iot-python/blob/master/src/ibmiotf/application.py#L258).

The 5th argument would just be `json`.

```
client.publishEvent("raspberrypi", options["deviceId"], "input", "json", myData)
```

EDIT:
Updated the [source code](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/python-iot-raspberry-pi).

Comment: @jdistler if the above answer worked for you can you please upvote and accept?

Answer (score -1):

In the comments of the tutorial "Mike D" said:

> This problem is covered in the IBM board. You now have to specify the message packing.

Comment: It refers to a post of "Kicke". He has got the same problem like you. I don´t know if my answer helps but maybe you can search for this message packing mentioned by Mike D.